# Can I mirror around a cylinder

Tags: modeling, mirror

I am trying to create a propeller but I want all sides of the propeller to mirror around a cylinder. If I edit one face of the outside of the cylinder, I want it to copy that to all the other sides of it. How could this be done?

Comment: Probably an array modifier rotated around the center point

Comment: or a Simple Deform modifier (Bend mode), but maybe show a reference picture if you have one

Answer (score 0):

what about this?

[image]

first model the propeller, then separate the object from the cylinder and give it a mirror modifier.

Comment: I need 16 blades

Comment: Hi Jett t, i know you are new here, and if of course you can comment to an answer, which might have needed 30 mins to make it "i need 16 blades" instead of "thank you very much for your effort, but unfortunately i forgot to mention in my question, that i need 16 blades, i will edit and update my question". And so my comment to your comment is: please edit and update your question that it is crystal clear what you want and keep this in mind for future questions. "Updating" a question by just comments is pretty bad behaviour and not useful. Thanks.